# Detecting if windows service is already installed using puppet exec

Tags: windows, powershell, puppet, puppet-enterprise

I have below `exec` resource which is used to install a window service.

I want to it to execute only if the window service is not installed. So I use the `onlyif` command but the command is not working. It is running the install all the time:

```
exec { "install-${target_path}/${binary_name}":
    command   => "${installUtil_filepath} /i /servicename=\"${service_name}\" /displayname=\"${display_name}\" /description=\"${description}\" \"${target_path}\\${binary_name}\"",
    onlyif    => "if((Get-Service \"${service_name}\" -ErrorAction SilentContinue).DisplayName -eq  ${display_name}) { exit 1 } else { exit 0 }",
    logoutput => true,
    provider => powershell,
  }
```

This worked

```
if(Get-Service \"${service_name}\") { exit 1 } else { exit 0 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you first retrive the service using the service name and then also compare the display name? You can probably omit that check...

Also, don't you want to exit with `exit 0` when the service is installed and otherwise with `1`?

Try this:

```
onlyif    => "if(Get-Service ${service_name}) { exit 0 } else { exit 1 }",
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. if(Get-Service \"${service_name}\") { exit 1 } else { exit 0 }